# BaseX GUI: Writeback not setting to true

Tags: xquery, basex

I am using BaseX 7.9 and want to set the WRITEBACK option to true. So, I execute `db:writeback[true]` on the Editor window

The Query Info shows:

```
Compiling:
- removing unknown element/attribute true
- db:writeback[()]: removing ()
Query:
db:writeback[true]
Optimized Query:
()
Result:
- Hit(s): 0 Items
- Updated: 0 Items
- Printed: 0 Bytes
- Read Locking: local [prueba_08242014_01]
- Write Locking: none
Timing:
- Parsing: 0.93 ms
- Compiling: 0.27 ms
- Evaluating: 0.42 ms
- Printing: 1.24 ms
- Total Time: 2.86 ms
Query plan:
<QueryPlan>
  <Empty size="0"/>
</QueryPlan>
```

Yet, then when I execute `db:system()`, WRITEBACK appears as false on the result window:

```
<system>
  <localoptions>
    ...
    <writeback>false</writeback>
    ...
  </localoptions>
</system>
```

(It is abbreviated)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What Went Wrong

BaseX automatically registers the `db` prefix for the `http://basex.org/modules/db` namespace. Your code is evaluated as XQuery, and returns all root elements in the `db` namespace with local name `writeback`, and then filters those with a predicate for those having a `true` child node. An input document that would match this query is

```xml
<writeback xmlns="http://basex.org/modules/db"><true/></writeback>
```

#### Modifying Options

To modify options in BaseX, use the [`SET [option] [value]` command](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Commands#SET) in the *Command* input.

[image: Example screenshot]